# User Mapping - Grant Permissions to db

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently pursue to hand out permission to an user (instance level) via the following command:

### Query

```
USE tempDbXY
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'User_XY'
GO
```

### Error Message

```
Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 37
User or role 'User_XY' does not exist in this database.
```

Unfortunately, the stored procedure only takes users currently existing in the database and completely ignores any users on the instance level.

How can I circumvent this and create a mapping (like it's done via UI) without creating an additional local user for the db?

I couldn't find any information in the [offical documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) from Microsoft. Apparently, they always assume that a local user already exists.